error bound for linear interpolation of lipschitz
Let f be a Lipschitz function. Do we have any error bound for its linear interpolation?
Any reference is appreciated. We do not know whether f is differntiable, all we know it is convex in a compact interval.
I have searched but not found

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To be more specific, I have a black box convex function in a closed interval and using interpolation for some reason and want to know error, thats all
